# Pandas, how to calculate delta between one cell and another in different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have the following frame:

```
USERID, EVENT1TIME, EVENT2TIME, MISC1, MISC2
123,45,,, 
123,,46,,
123,,47,,
123,,48,,
123,,49,,
123,,51,,
124,45,,, 
124,,46,,
124,,47,,
124,,48,,
124,,49,,
124,,51,,
```

I'd like to add a 4th column that is (EVENT2TIME - EVENT1TIME)

```
USERID, EVENT1TIME, EVENT2TIME, MISC1, MISC2, DELTA
123,45,,,, 
123,,46,,,1
123,,47,,,2
123,,48,,,3
123,,49,,,4
123,,51,,,6
124,45,,,, 
124,,46,,,1
124,,47,,,2
124,,48,,,3
124,,49,,,4
124,,51,,,6
```

I think the first thing to do is to copy the value from the row where EVENT1TIME is populated into the other instances of that USERID. But I suspect there may be a better way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to clarify, do you specifically want to calculate the difference between `EVENT1TIME` of the 1st row to the `EVENT2TIME` of all the other rows?

Comment: Are you trying to get the difference between the first row and all other rows?

Comment: If you want to find the difference between `EVENT2TIME` and first row of `EVENT1TIME`, then you can give `df['DELTA'] = df.iloc[:,2] - df.iloc[0,1]`

Comment: The EVENT1TIME needs to be calculated per USERID. There are many USERID entries.

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions:

1. You want to calculate the difference between column `EVENT2TIME` and first row of `EVENT1TIME`
2. You want to store the results into `DELTA`

You can do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('abc.txt')
print (df)
df['DELTA'] = df.iloc[:,2] - df.iloc[0,1]
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
   USERID   EVENT1TIME   EVENT2TIME  MISC1 MISC2  DELTA
0     123         45.0          NaN    NaN          NaN
1     123          NaN         46.0    NaN   NaN    1.0
2     123          NaN         47.0    NaN   NaN    2.0
3     123          NaN         48.0    NaN   NaN    3.0
4     123          NaN         49.0    NaN   NaN    4.0
5     123          NaN         51.0    NaN   NaN    6.0
```

Comment: There are mare than one USERID entries. I have update the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know `EVENT1TIME` is always and only in the first row, just store it as a variable and subtract it.

```py
val = df.EVENT1TIME[0]
df['DELTA'] = df.EVENT2TIME - val
```

If you have multiple values every so often in `EVENT1TIME`, use some logic to back or forward fill all the empty rows for `EVENT1TIME`. This fill is not stored in the final output df.

```py
df['DELTA'] = df.EVENT2TIME - df.EVENT1TIME.ffill()  # forward fill (down) all nan values
# OR
df['DELTA'] = df.EVENT2TIME - df.EVENT1TIME.bfill()  # back fill (up) all nan values
```

EDIT: Keeping this for continuity despite how hacky it is.

```py
locations = list(df[~np.isnan(df.EVENT1TIME)].index)
vals = df.EVENT1TIME.loc[locations]  # all EVENT1TIME values
locations.append(df.EVENT1TIME.index[-1]+1)  # last row index + 1

last_loc = locations[0]
for idx, next_loc in enumerate(locations[1:]):
    temp = df.loc[last_loc:next_loc-1]
    df['DELTA'].loc[last_loc:next_loc-1] = temp.EVENT2VALUE - vals[last_loc]
    last_loc = next_loc
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm trying to do. I think a way to backfill based on the USERID what what I originally was trying to suggest.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you did here:

```# create a variable that holds all the location information for the instances of no NaN entries in the EVENT1TIME column

locations = list(df[~np.isnan(df.EVENT1TIME)].index)```

Comment: The EVENT1TIME entries were originally in a separate df. Maybe I should have used a more intelligent way to merge the data. Maybe a directional (left, right) merge would be able to "backfill" those entires.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the `locations` variable. Note this for loop method does the same thing as the `ffill` or `bfill` solutions. If you share what your original data looks like, we can help identify the best complete solution. Otherwise we can only help identify small steps along the way.

Comment: If you have two data frames to begin with, perhaps look at `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='USERID')`. This will perform filling based on the specified column name.